# enqueue an element without changing the structure

Tags: java, queue, performance

Is there a way to return a queue after calling an enqueue function such that the returned queue contains the new element and the original queue remains the same?

e.g.

```
ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(list);
result.add(0, t);
return result;
```

This would return a new queue but this approach is too slow.
is there any other way? perhaps by sharing the structure with the original queue?

The main question is how to return a new queue (after appending an element to the queue) but without copying the rest of the original queue. (is there a way to refer it?)

e.g. original_queue=[1 2 3 4 5]

call enqueue(6) should return [1 2 3 4 5 6]

but original_queue=[1 2 3 4 5]

Comment: Without knowing what your use case is, it's difficult to offer advice.  If you told us what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to offer you a better way to achieve the same thing, perhaps without using separate queues/lists at all.

Comment: So basically, what you want is a persistent queue?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Example: *"I have a basketball simulation game, and I'm representing basketballs as items in a queue.  I want to add new basketballs, but split the new ones into new games while retaining them in the original game.  I'm currently doing this with ArrayLists, but it's too slow.  Is there any way to do it faster?"*

Comment: @robert ive given an example , theres no task im trying to achieve as such. just trying to achieve the example ive mentioned

Comment: It's entirely possible that what you're asking from your computer is already consuming the minimum number of clock cycles.  Newing up an ArrayList each time is not exactly a cost-free operation.

Comment: is it not possible to refer the original queue anyhow? wihtout copying it?

Comment: @drarkayl You either have one queue or two. If you have one queue, it can't have both 5 and 6 elements. If you want a second queue, you're going to have to make a copy. And "too slow" is probably a fiction. Do you have a production environment with a performance problem that you've traced back to making a copy of a list?

Answer (score 0):

[CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) may be an alternative for your queue, that may have the behaviour you want. No comment on whether this will be efficient enough for your purposes.

Comment: this doesnt really change the efficency. its the same as before. :)